# How to make an image fill the entire div on hover?

Tags: html, css

I want an image to show up on the div when I hover it. The code I am using makes the image larger than the div, how can I contain it to the fill the size of the div and not leak?

Here is the CSS code:

```
  img{
    display: none;
    max-height: 50vh;
  }
  .effect:hover .text{
    display: none;
  }
  .effect:hover img{
    display: block;
  }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 alternate_2 effect">
            <h1 class="display-6 text">Studio Griot</h1>
            <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Shalaj.JPG"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 effect">
            <h1 class="display-6 text">Web Development</h1>
            <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Shalaj.JPG"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 alternate_2 effect">
            <h1 class="display-6 text">Data Visualisation</h1>
            <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Shalaj.JPG"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 effect">
            <h1 class="display-6 text">Incrediminds</h1>
            <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Shalaj.JPG"/>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks For The Help

Comment: Add `width: 100%` to the `img`. That will make it so it only expands to the width of the container.

Comment: Should I remove the max-height: 50vh;?

Comment: You don't need it - so you can. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT with what OP actually wanted.

Here is the image that takes up the full width and height without stretching. You can use `object-fit: cover`

Information on `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
img {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.effect:hover .text {
  display: none;
}

.effect:hover img {
  display: block;
}

h1.text {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 alternate_2 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Studio Griot</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Web Development</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 alternate_2 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Data Visualisation</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Incrediminds</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add `width: 100%` to the img. That will keep it 100% width of its parent. I changed your bootstrap markup to `col-sm` so you could see it when you run the snippet.

#### Added information for future visitors:

An `img` will always display as large as its own default/native size, unless you specify the `width: 100%` and make sure it is `display: block`, since `img` are `inline` by default.

```css
img {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.effect:hover .text {
  display: none;
}

.effect:hover img {
  display: block;
}

h1.text {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 alternate_2 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Studio Griot</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Web Development</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 alternate_2 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Data Visualisation</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 effect">
    <h1 class="display-6 text">Incrediminds</h1>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium dui ultrices, ornare mauris in, ultricies sapien. Proin dictum urna quis mauris pharetra, sit amet aliquam diam suscipit. In congue.</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500/500" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This keeps it from leeking out of the div, but it does not fill it. I want it to fill the div without stretching out.

Comment: the `object-fit` rule does not work on IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit. You should do it with `min-width: 100%;min-height:100%;width:100%;height:auto;` and then use `translate` to center the image without deforming it. that will work in all browsers

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's only E11 and older versions of Edge - which Microsoft no longer supports. As a full time web dev, I won't support IE unless the client specifically pays for it.

Comment: object-fit: cover; isnt working for me on chrome, should it?

Comment: Same here. Full time web dev. The solutions you decide to use should still cover IE11 because it still has 2%+ market share according to this: https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php. So, even though `object-fit` is a very neat solution (that is also the reason why I upvoted your solution), I would not recommend it yet if the OP needs it to work on IE as well :)

Comment: @ShalajWadhwa yes, it should

Comment: @CornelRaiu sure, I get it. I just think we need to start moving the web forward. I understand that some enterprise clients will be stuck on IE11, because of internal concerns. I also see the trend of IE11 continuing to drop. But, to your point, we recently had a request to make something look better in IE9! If someone is paying, I guess we'll do it :)

Comment: @disinfor I feel sorry for you :) I really do :))